# What are the free resources to learn english online?

Tags: discussion, resources, online-resources

My wife wants to improve her English.

It's a paid site to learn english

https://id.engbreaking.com/

I wonder if there is any like that that is free?

Comment: Unless you're dealing with a native speaking human teacher (not a recording, not software), I don't recommend any paid online English teaching site. There is no accountability and no regulation; they're happy to take your money, I'm sure.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is more relevant to [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com) and indeed it's well answered with lots of resources in the Meta on that site: [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english). Some of the resources mentioned there are free.

The mechanics of migration and closing as a duplicate mean that leaving this question here as a signpost to ELL is worthwhile.

Comment: Also [LanguageLearning.SE]